# How to know if UEFI Shell is booting in 64-bit or 32-bit?

Tags: uefi

I intend to write a script in startup.nsh to handle different tasks on 32-bit and 64-bit. But I do not know how to retrieve this information.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to write stuff within .nsh, a quick way to verify this would be to place 2 dummy .efi programs on the file system, one compiled as IA32 and another one X64.

Then you try to run both programs from your .nsh script. The one who runs correctly tells what architecture your system has.

Another way would be to put in your pendrive files like BOOTIA32, and BOOTX64. The one who gets executed fills some variable or writes some file in the file system indicating the current architecture, and then gives place to the shell.

I'll try to search for better approaches (maybe some shell tool with no workarounds); if I find anything I'll add to my answer.

**UPDATE:** you can also use the **smbiosview** utility from the UEFI Shell. You can search for specific structure types, by doing like:

```
smbiosview -t <structure_type>
```

And you can try to check the following structure types:

- 4 (processor information): can retrieve info like "64-bit capable processor"
- 18 (32-bit error information): info regarding 32-bit
- 33 (64-bit error information): info regarding 64-bit, if supported

Comment: Having a 64-bit CPU means your firmware ***could*** be 64-bit. But it doesn't mean it is. And querying the two "memory error" structures doesn't return anything on my tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple EFI Byte Code application which:

1. calls some interface function with invalid params
2. checks returned status code (bit 31 is set = IA32; bit 63 is set = x64, etc.)
3. exits with corresponding status code (e.g. 1 = IA32, 2 = x64, etc.)

Assembly code for such application could look something like:

```
      movnw r1, @r0(+1, +16)
      movnw r2, @r0(+0, +16)
      xor32 r3, r3
      pushn r3
      pushn r3
      pushn r3
      movnw r1, @r1(EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE.BootServices)
      callex @r1(EFI_BOOT_SERVICES.AllocatePool)
      movn r7, r7
      movib @r0, 0x32
      cmpi32eq r7, 0x80000002
      jmpcs @f
      movib @r0, 0x64
    @@:
      pushn r2
      callex @r1(EFI_BOOT_SERVICES.Exit)
```

Here's Base64-encoded application binary itself

> TVoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAFBFAAC8DgIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcAAiAAsCAQBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAQAAIAEAAAAAAAEAAAAAIAAAACAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAYAEAACABAAAAAAAACgAAAAAAEAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAudGV4dAAAADQAAAAgAQAAQAAAACABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAABgLmRhdGEAAAAAAAAAYAEAAAAAAABgAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAYAAAAAAAAAAAcoFBEHKCEAAWMzUDNQM1A3KRiSGDKYUBABAyd3cIMgCtBwIAAIDCAncIZAA1AoMpGBgAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==

And usage example screenshot:

[image]